# Software unable to use installed fonts in Windows 10

Tags: display, windows-10, fonts, itunes

the Segoe UI used in iTunes cannot be displayed

[image: pic here]

next the following software also cannot display its default fonts (the default fonts were installed successfully)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTjp9.png]

so may I know anyone has also encounted this issue and is there any solution to it?